# Is it possible to add "Synonyms and Antonyms" to the rightclick menu like office word and do the replacement in place?

Tags: replacement, notebooks

When we write some note or comments in the notebook, Mathematica provides a spell check and we can select the right word to replace it. Mathematica 12.0 also provides a function to find the Synonyms of a word, for example,

```
    In[1]:= Synonyms["functional"]

    Out[1]= {"operable", "operational", "operative", "running", "usable", "useable", "working"}

    In[2]:= Synonyms["forget"]

    Out[2]= {"blank out", "block", "bury", "draw a blank", "leave"}

    In[3]:= Antonyms["functional"]

    Out[3]= {"nonfunctional", "organic"}
```

This function is very useful, but it can only be processed in cell evalutation. When I wrote some comments, I want to use some other words to improve my wirtting. I know in microsoft office word, there is a synonyms and antonyms replacement.

Can we do that in Mathematica?